# ng config -g cli.defaultCollection @schematics/angular@8.3.25 error

Tags: angular, npm, frontend, angular-cli, config

when i'm trying to solve sames problems i set this command
`ng config -g cli.defaultCollection @schematics/angular@8.3.25`

after when i trie to create a new project with ng new my-app i see this problem :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@schematics/angular@8.3.25"
"C:\\Users\\user-name".
See "C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-NZgwJc\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

if someone help me  i will appreciate that i'm working on this problem from 5 days if you have any idea i will be happy to see its ?

i'm trying to use ng cmd to create new project with ng new

Comment: You should never globally set an Angular setting specific to a version. It will only work in this specific version. I'm not surprised that it causes issues with projects generated by `ng new`. Whatever the original problem is, the solution is very bad, you should find another solution.